# c++ cast vector<unsigned char> to unsigned char *

Tags: c++

I've got 
    `std::vector<unsigned char> data = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01};` - the function I'm passing this to requires `unsigned char *` - I do the following : `unsigned char * converted = static_cast<unsigned char*>(data.data());` and I then pass converted to the function. I'll be using that extensively throughout the code. I prefer to work with vectors as I find them easier to handle. Now the question is - is that cast safe - I mean can I count on it that it'll always work or is it a slow or a bad approach? If so, what's a better way to do it?

regards.

Comment: Nothing really wrong, given the fact that you haven't given us much code to judge on.

Comment: I figure you know not to resize the vector.

Comment: It doesn't look like the cast is even necessary to me... `data()` returns an `unsigned char*`

Comment: `std::vector<T>::data()` returns a non-const `T*` if called on a non-const `vector` object, so you don't need the cast: `unsigned char * converted = data.data();` However, if you have a const `vector` object (say, an input parameter to a function), you can use `const_cast` instead: `unsigned char * converted = const_cast<unsigned char*>(data.data());` Though this is not advisable if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 7):

What about

```
 std::vector<unsigned char> data;
 unsigned char* converted = &data[0];
```

?

Comment: As noted in the duplicate question, this is [guaranteed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#69) by the spec.

Comment: thanks - much better indeed

Answer (score 1):

`(data.size()? &data.front():nullptr)` avoids any need for a cast.

Comment: even better... works a charm - thank you people - the better I get the more I realise how little I know...